# ConcurrentModificationException Error in ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpool

I create ThreadPoolTaskExecutor using configuration annotation like this

```
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer, EnvironmentAware {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncConfiguration.class);

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, "async.");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        log.debug("Creating Async Task Executor");
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(propertyResolver.getProperty("corePoolSize", Integer.class, 30));
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(propertyResolver.getProperty("maxPoolSize", Integer.class, 150));
        executor.setQueueCapacity(propertyResolver.getProperty("queueCapacity", Integer.class, 10000));
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("app-Executor-");
        return new ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }
}
```

I use ThreadPoolExecutor in this class

```
@Component
public class TrapReceiver extends Thread implements CommandResponder {

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Inject
    private Executor executor;

    public TrapReceiver(){
    }

    List<PDUv1> listPdu = new ArrayList<PDUv1>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.start();
    }

    public synchronized void processPdu(CommandResponderEvent cmdRespEvent) {
        PDUv1 pdu = (PDUv1) cmdRespEvent.getPDU();
        listPdu.add(pdu);
        if (pdu != null) {
            if(listPdu.size() == 3){ //3 pdu per thread
                List<PDUv1> temp = new ArrayList<PDUv1>();
                temp.addAll(listPdu);
                TrapInsertor trapInsertor = (TrapInsertor) applicationContext.getBean("trapInsertor");
                trapInsertor.setProperty(temp);
                executor.execute(trapInsertor);
                listPdu.clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my thread class

```
public class TrapInsertor implements Runnable {

    @Inject
    private TrapProcessorService trapProcessorService;

    private List<PDUv1> listPdu;

    public void setProperty(List<PDUv1> listPdu){
        this.listPdu = listPdu;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start process "+listPdu.size()+" PDU");
            for(PDUv1 pdu : listPdu){
                String[] varBinding = pdu.getVariableBindings().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(", ");
                trapProcessorService.processTrap(varBinding);
            }
            listPdu.clear();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
        }
    }
}
```

but sometimes I got error like this

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at app.snmp.test.TrapInsertor.run(TrapInsertor.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

also like this

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:239)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:214)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:497)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at app.snmp.test.service.TrapProcessorService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3d040253.processTrap(<generated>)
    at app.snmp.test.TrapInsertor.run(TrapInsertor.java:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$1.convert(MySQLDialect.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3281)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1288)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementProxy.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementProxy.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 27 more
```

What is wrong in my code? If that error caused by listPdu collection is shared between thread?
........

The ConcurrentModificationException error is solved by adding scope prototype in this configuration class. Prototype means that new bean instance will created each time when requested. Thanks @Vladimir Sitnikov

```
@Configuration
public class TrapProcessorComponentConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public TrapInsertor trapInsertor(){
        return new TrapInsertor();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your spring configuration. You are likely reusing the same `trapInsertor` instance, thus all the exceptions.

Is your "trapInsertor" bean a singleton bean? I think beans are singletons by default in spring.

See what can happen:

1. You collect 3 items
2. Call `trapInsertor.setProperty(temp);` // say it is arrayList1
3. Call `executor.execute(trapInsertor);`, but the trapInsertor does not yet start (it might take a while before thread pool picks up the work)
4. You collect 3 more items
5. Call `trapInsertor.setProperty(temp);` // say it is arrayList2
6. Call `executor.execute(trapInsertor);`
7. Now the actions from #3 and #6 start to work. It might happen they both see the same `arrayList2`.

So you can have have:

1. Data loss. Basically, `arrayList1` is not processed at all!
2. One thread iterating over the list `for(PDUv1 pdu : listPdu){` (in `TrapInsertor`) and another one performing `listPdu.clear()` (in `TrapInsertor`). This results in `ConcurrentModificationException`.
3. Both threads might write data to the database, thus lock each other, thus `MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock;`

I would recommend you should *recreate* the task you submit to the executor.
In other words you need something like `scope="prototype"` (see [How do I force a spring container not to return a singleton instance of a bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444623/how-do-i-force-a-spring-container-not-to-return-a-singleton-instance-of-a-bean))

Comment: The problem seems solved, no error until now (I have run my thread for 20minutes)
But still not sure if MySQLTransactionRollbackException error also solved :)

Comment: MySQLTransactionRollbackException could still be there if you happen to receive multiple traps for the same entity at approximately the same time and you logic tries to update the row. If that is the case, an easiest solution would be to sort PDUs (e.g. by its primary key) before storing to the database. That would eliminate dead-locks.

Answer (score -1):

You could make a defensive copy of the list being processed, just modify `TrapInsertor.setProperty()` to something like:

`public void setProperty(List<PDUv1> listPdu){
        this.listPdu = new ArrayList<PDUv1>(listPdu);
    }`

This way, each thread will work with its own instance of list, thus preventing concurrent modifications.

Comment: Even if this happen to mask CME (it does not prevent CME in the current case due to race condition of clear and your "defensive copy"),

1. it will still not protect two threads from operating on exactly the same data.
2. Mahadi could loss some data (see my answer)

Comment: I had tried like this before because I think the error is caused by listPdu is shared between thread. And it's did not solve my problem. I think @VladimirSitnikov answer is right. I reuse the same trapInsertor because it singleton