# What's the best way to turn a single @Component instance into multiple ones?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring application which create a task which schedules and runs a Runnable:

**MAIN:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class Main {
    @Autowired
    CoinListerTask coinListerTask;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }


    @Component
    public class CommandLineAppStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
        @Override
        public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
            ... 

            // start coin listing job           
            coinListerTask.startup();
```

**TASK:**

```
@Component
public class CoinListerTask {
    private TimeUnit timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
    private String threadName = "coin-lister";

    @Value("${coindatabase.coinlister.initialDelay}")
    private long initalDelay;

    @Value("${coindatabase.coinlister.period}")
    private long period;

    private String exchangeNameString = "Cryptopia";

    @Autowired
    private IDataService dataService;

    @Autowired
    CoinDbService dbService;

    public void startup() {
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = new WrappedScheduledExecutor(threadName, 1, false);
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableTask, initalDelay, period, timeUnit);   

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Shutdown.runner(executorService, threadName, 60L);
            }
        });
    }

    Runnable runnableTask = () -> {
            // do stuff...
    }
```

This works fine as-is, but I would now like to generalise it so I can run multiple instances of the task with sets of different parameters specified via application.properties replacing variables that are currently autowired.

Should I just remove @Component and pass everything in to instances created with new, or is there a better, more spring-appropriate way to achieve this?

**SOLUTION**

To expand on Lino and Visal's solution:

1. Add to the component:
   @Scope("prototype")
2. Replace the @Autowire of the component with:
   @Autowired
   Provider coinListerTaskProvider;
3. Change the invocation of the task to:
   coinListerTaskProvider.get().startup();

The Provider is available by adding javax/javaee-api/6.0

Comment: Maybe using `@Component(scope="prototype")` will do the trick. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444623/how-do-i-force-a-spring-container-not-to-return-a-singleton-instance-of-a-bean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a new instance whenever you call use the Scope annotaion with component,service,controller,repository etc like :-

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
```

where prototype define scope i.e give always a new instance whenever you call.

see the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html) of scope